# Need of xpath:position & xpath:attribute

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

I am working on a record tool (in JavaScript) similar to Selenium. For Playback I need the XPath position and its attributes (see below screenshot from Selenium).

How can I find the position and attributes in JavaScript?

[image: Selenium Tool snip for reference]

Comment: Improved formatting and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector:

```
document.querySelector("li:nth-of-type(4) input[name='leg0']");
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll("li:nth-of-type(4) input[name='leg0']");
```

Comment: I dont need the particular element for selection.I need the above two attributes(postion & attribute) for any selected element that i click.The above screenshots shows a defined example which is only for reference.

Comment: For *any* element? You can get css selector for any given element, but the given element might not be selectable by position. And it might not have the attribute you want.

Comment: I can't use it as my element is decided based on Mouse Click.But,my doubt is how come SELENIUM find its attributes and position?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean? Selenium finds elements based on xpath, css or HTML attributes.

Comment: Yes. Please use the Selenium WebDriver Addon for reference.